# Zeros of nontrivial solution to 2nd order ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

Claim: Any non trivial solution to:$\ y''+\dfrac{(2-x^2)y}{4}=0$ has at most $1$ zero in $\mathbb{R} \ $

May I verify if my proof is correct?

$y_1=e^{-\frac{x^2}{4}}$ is a solution to the differential equation. Let $y_2$ be any nontrivial solution that is linearly independent to $y_1.$ If $y_2$ has two zeros $z_1,z_2$, then by Sturm Separation Theorem, $y_1$ has one zero between $z_1,z_2.$ Contradiction.

Thank you.